# Not importing podfile in our project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using Xcode 7 for ios development. I'm new to Swift. I use in my project CocoaPods. But I'm unable to import the files into our project.

MY Cocoapodfile is

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'SCLAlertView2' do
pod 'SCLAlertView'

end

target 'IceCreamShopTests' do

end
```

Podfiles are created. But I'm unable to import the files.

```
import SCLAlertView
```

I'm getting no such module error getting. How to resolve it. Any help welcome.

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace and not the xcproj ? Did you do the pod update/install?

Comment: Yes i open scworkspace file. @Larme

Answer (score 0):

Not only podfile has to be created, you also have to run

```
pod install
```

Or, if you already installed and you want to update/add new libraries:

```
pod update
```

Then, build the project again (Command+B)

Comment: But I'm getting 300 error's in SCLAlertView.swift file. I'm using xcode 7.2.

Comment: Maybe the SCLAlertView is using another version of Swift. Go to sclalertview settings and enable "use legacy"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the "Getting Started" instructions at [cocoapods.org](http://cocoapods.org/#get_started). Here are the specific steps listed:

1. List the dependencies in a text file named Podfile in your Xcode project directory:

   `platform :ios, '8.0'
   use_frameworks!
   target 'MyApp' do
     pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
     pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
     pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
   end`

Tip: CocoaPods provides a pod init command to create a Podfile with smart defaults. You should use it.

2. Now you can install the dependencies in your project:

$ pod install
Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of the project file when building your project:

$ open App.xcworkspace
Now you can import your dependencies e.g.:

```
#import <Reachability/Reachability.h>
```